# Are Overriden methods in the subclass used for other subclass?

Tags: java

I have a Battleship as a superclass
Minesweeper and Cruiser as children of the class Battleship.
In the Battleship class I have a method called hit, and this method is override in the the Minesweeper class. But when I try to access the 'hit' method in the Battleship for the class Cruiser it goes to the 'hit' method in the Minesweeper class.

Battleship Class:

```
public class Battleship 
{
    private Part[] part;



    public Battleship(int row, int sizeofTheShip)
    {
            part = new Part[sizeofTheShip];

            for(int i=0; i< sizeofTheShip; i++)
            {
                part[i] = new Part(row,i);
            }

    }

    public boolean hit(int row, int column)

    {

        Part newpart = new Part(row,column);

        for(int i=0; i<part.length;i++)
        {
            if (part[i].equals(newpart))
            {
                part[i].setDestroyed(true);
                return true;
            }
        }

    return false; 
 }
```

Cruiser class:

```
public class Cruiser extends Battleship
{
    public Cruiser(int row)
    {
        super(row,4);
    }

}
```

Minesweeper class:

```
public class Minesweeper extends Battleship 
{
    public Minesweeper(int row)
    {
        super(row,2);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hit(int row, int column)
    {
        double random = Math.random();

        if (random > 0.5)
        {
            super.hit(row, column);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }



}
```

The Board Class:

```
public class Board 
{
private ArrayList<Battleship> battleships = new ArrayList<Battleship>();

public Board()
{
    battleships.add(new Battleship(0,5));
    battleships.add(new Cruiser(1));
    battleships.add(new Minesweeper(2));


}

public boolean hit(int row, int column)

{

    for (Battleship b: battleships)
    {

        if (b.hit(row, column) == true)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

Please if something is not clear let me know in the comment, I will edit the post to make more sense

Thanks for your time

Comment: Prove your assertion as it's hard to believe that it's happening -- create and post your valid [mcve] that shows what you're telling us.

Comment: What evidence do you have to support your claim?

Comment: Do you mean in your IDE? State your problem more clearly. Provide examples.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I tried my best to include relative information to the problem as the code is much longer. I will try and reedit it again. thanks

Comment: how are you calling this code?

Comment: @J.Marsomn: Your code shows nothing backing what on the surface seems like outrageous program behavior. If we're to understand or even believe what you're telling us, we will need runnable code, a [mcve] where you post a small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem for us. It is posted here in your question as code-formatted text as you're doing now, but is compilable and runnable.

Comment: Extraordinary claims demand extraordinary proof. You're basically saying that Java inheritance is broken, which in general, isn't the case. It's far more likely there's an issue in your code. Without enough context it's impossible to point you in this more-likely direction in a focused manner.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm calling it from the for each loop in the Board class which has been added. thanks

Comment: OK, how does that posted code prove your assertion? Do you give your methods println statements to tell you what classes their from and which method is being called?

Comment: @DaveNewton The evidence for my claim is that in the for each loop in the Board class. When b is Cruiser it goes to the method 'hit' in the Minesweeper class. I had a print statement that easily showed that. Thanks

Comment: Or are you tracing  with a debugger? It's easier if you tell us what's actually happening compared to your expectations rather than us having to figure everything out ourselves.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Yes, I have done that and when b is Cruiser it goes to the method 'hit' in the Minesweeper class!

Comment: @J.Marsomn I flat-out don't believe you. Sorry. Print out all the relevant values and include the traces in the methods in question and include it in your post.

Comment: This is simply a game that has different kind of ships and in the board class I make those ships. In the main method ( which is not included ) I pass the user input to hit a part of the ship depending on the row and column input. If the row and cloumn had an object of part it will return true, otherwise it will return false

Comment: This isn't really that hard. Make the first line of of `Battleship.hit` `System.out.println("B hit");`. Make the first line of `Minesweeper.hit` `System.out.println("M hit");`. Then run your code, and show us the output.

Comment: Is here anyone interested of me sending the whole code ? I would really appreciate it, you might even like the game ! :D

Comment: @Iluvatar I got this output : B hit
B hit
M hit

Comment: Then clearly you're doing something different from the code you've posted here, as you only show three ships.

Comment: For what input? This is why I said print out *all* relevant values. Understand our position: you're stating that Java is fundamentally broken. I claim that 99.9% of the time it isn't. I believe the error lies either in your code, or your assumptions. Without context we're grasping at straws--but I'd be willing to bet that Java inheritance is working as it should in this case.

Comment: @DaveNewton I must be wrong then, as it works but I have missed up the logic of the program somewhere. I've been working on it for almost 10 hours :D ! thanks again for your replies

Comment: @J.Marsomn Agreed: you changed your comment; if you're looping through the three ships, and you see to Battleship `hit`s and a `Minesweeper` hit, that's expected behavior. Although depending on where you put your print statement, you should possibly be seeing both an `M` and a `B` for the minesweeper hits.

Comment: Also, how do you place your ships vertically in this game? In real battleship they can go both horizontally and vertically. I'm not sure I understand the value of a `Part` class here either.

Comment: @ DaveNewton this is a simplified example of it which only accepts it horizontally and starting from column 0

Comment: Thanks for everyone commented, the solution of my problem was that I had to cast when the ship was of type Minesweeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertion proven false:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Board {
    private ArrayList<Battleship> battleships = new ArrayList<Battleship>();

    public Board() {
        battleships.add(new Battleship("Battleship", 0, 5));
        battleships.add(new Cruiser("Cruiser", 1));
        battleships.add(new Minesweeper("Minesweeper", 2));
    }

    public boolean hit(int row, int column) {
        for (Battleship b : battleships) {
            if (b.hit(row, column) == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board board = new Board();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                board.hit(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

}

class Battleship {
    private Part[] part;
    private String name;

    public Battleship(String name, int row, int sizeofTheShip) {
        this.name = name;
        part = new Part[sizeofTheShip];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeofTheShip; i++) {
            part[i] = new Part(row, i);
        }
    }

    public boolean hit(int row, int column) {
        System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", getName(), "From Battleship");
        Part newpart = new Part(row, column);
        for (int i = 0; i < part.length; i++) {
            if (part[i].equals(newpart)) {
                part[i].setDestroyed(true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

class Cruiser extends Battleship {
    public Cruiser(String name, int row) {
        super(name, row, 4);
    }
}

class Minesweeper extends Battleship {
    public Minesweeper(String name, int row) {
        super(name, row, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hit(int row, int column) {
        System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", getName(), "From Minesweeper");
        double random = Math.random();
        if (random > 0.5) {
            super.hit(row, column);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class Part {
    private int row;
    private int i;
    private boolean destroyed;

    public Part(int row, int i) {
        this.row = row;
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void setDestroyed(boolean destroyed) {
        this.destroyed = destroyed;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public boolean isDestroyed() {
        return destroyed;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Part [row=" + row + ", i=" + i + ", destroyed=" + destroyed + "]";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Minesweeper: From Battleship
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Minesweeper: From Battleship
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Minesweeper: From Battleship
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Minesweeper: From Battleship
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Minesweeper: From Battleship
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Minesweeper: From Battleship
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Minesweeper: From Battleship
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Minesweeper: From Battleship
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Minesweeper: From Battleship
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Minesweeper: From Battleship
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Minesweeper: From Battleship
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
Battleship: From Battleship
Cruiser: From Battleship
Minesweeper: From Minesweeper
```

All Cruiser's hit methods were from Battleship

So the direct answer for your question:

> Are Overriden methods in the subclass used for other subclass?

is no. You're somehow misinterpreting the data.

Comment: Can I please send my code to you as a zip file to email or something and see where I have gone wrong ?

Comment: @J.Marsomn: no. No one wants to see your whole code, nor should we. Please remember that we're all volunteers helping on our free time, and if you need further help, it is in your best interest to make it easy for us to help you, including posting a valid [mcve] as I've done above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Got it thanks. Next time I will think of a simple scinario that covers my problem instead of posting the whole thing. But the thing is that in this particular problem everything is related and It's barely impossible to do that. Thanks for your help

Comment: @J.Marsomn: that suggests that you need to refactor your code. You want to make your classes with high cohesion and low coupling (check [wikipedia for definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))), coding to interfaces, and in doing so, you will make your code much easier to test in isolation.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I guess I'm not that advanced in programming to do that. I knew that the question does not make sense but I tried my best to make it so. Thanks again